# Configuring Protocol Buffers 0.9.x with Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, build.gradle, protocol-buffers, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've updated the protocol buffers version from 0.8.x to 0.9.1 on my Android project and I'm getting a gradle sync error. I have removed the imports from the `build.gradle.kts` file as per the documentation, and I'm getting an error as shown below.

This is the code in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:21.0-rc-1"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.plugins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error, which points to the `create("java") {` line - how can I configure protocol buffers using the Kotlin DSL?

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: ExecutableLocator with name 'java' not found.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:504)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:333)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask$_getAllExecutableLocators_closure8.doCall(GenerateProtoTask.groovy:354)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask.getAllExecutableLocators(GenerateProtoTask.groovy:354)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask.getReleaseExecutableLocators(GenerateProtoTask.groovy:350)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask.access$0(GenerateProtoTask.groovy)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask$_getExecutables_closure6.doCall(GenerateProtoTask.groovy:342)
        at com.google.protobuf.gradle.GenerateProtoTask$_getExecutables_closure6.call(GenerateProtoTask.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ProviderResolutionStrategy$2.resolve(ProviderResolutionStrategy.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.ProviderBackedFileCollection.visitDependencies(ProviderBackedFileCollection.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
        ... 141 more
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed to change it as shown below

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:21.0-rc-1"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.protobuf'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:21.0-rc-1"
    }
    plugins {
        create("grpc") { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.55.1" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
            task.plugins {
                create("grpc") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.55.1'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.55.1'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.55.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53'
}
```